# How to auto calculate the begin and end lines when including source files in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have the below in my documentation:

`#+INCLUDE: "code/basic.sv" :src systemverilog :lines "14-117"`

Here line 14 is where I have `class basic extends ..` and line 116 is where I have `endclass`.

Is there a way to auto insert the numbers 14 and 117 (=116+1) so that I don't have to manually update them every time I modify the `code/basic.sv`?

Comment: So you always want it to go from class to endclass?

Comment: No. That was an example. I am thinking of a solution where I can provide regex for begin and end lines.. Something would evaluate a function `org-include-src(FILE, LANGUAGE, REGEX_BEGIN, REGEX_END)`

Comment: One way is, placing some sort of unique markers (begin end) in the the included file and find them with a function which would be hooked to `org-export-before-processing-hook` to preprocess for the line numbers. Another way is just send a feature request mail to org mailing list :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is another option. This one is let's you customize the regular
expressions on a per-include basis. It should fit better with some
workflows as you're not limited to extension-based definitions.

### To Use

Do something like the following in your org-file. (The `:lines` keyword is optional)

```
#+INCLUDE: "code/my-class.sv" :src systemverilog :range-begin "^class" :range-end "^endclass" :lines "14-80"
```

The function will visit "my-class.sv" and search for those two
regexps, and then it will update the `:lines` keyword according with
the match result.

If `:range-begin` is missing, the range will be "-80".
If `:range-end` is missing, the range will be "14-".

### The Code

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'endless/update-includes)

(defun endless/update-includes (&rest ignore)
  "Update the line numbers of #+INCLUDE:s in current buffer.
Only looks at INCLUDEs that have either :range-begin or :range-end.
This function does nothing if not in org-mode, so you can safely
add it to `before-save-hook'."
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward-regexp
              "^\\s-*#\\+INCLUDE: *\"\\([^\"]+\\)\".*:range-\\(begin\\|end\\)"
              nil 'noerror)
        (let* ((file (expand-file-name (match-string-no-properties 1)))
               lines begin end)
          (forward-line 0)
          (when (looking-at "^.*:range-begin *\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"")
            (setq begin (match-string-no-properties 1)))
          (when (looking-at "^.*:range-end *\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"")
            (setq end (match-string-no-properties 1)))
          (setq lines (endless/decide-line-range file begin end))
          (when lines
            (if (looking-at ".*:lines *\"\\([-0-9]+\\)\"")
                (replace-match lines :fixedcase :literal nil 1)
              (goto-char (line-end-position))
              (insert " :lines \"" lines "\""))))))))

(defun endless/decide-line-range (file begin end)
  "Visit FILE and decide which lines to include.
BEGIN and END are regexps which define the line range to use."
  (let (l r)
    (save-match-data
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file file)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if (null begin)
            (setq l "")
          (search-forward-regexp begin)
          (setq l (line-number-at-pos (match-beginning 0))))
        (if (null end)
            (setq r "")
          (search-forward-regexp end)
          (setq r (1+ (line-number-at-pos (match-end 0)))))
        (format "%s-%s" l r)))))
```

Comment: This is great! Now I can use this to export multiple snippets from the same file. Snippet 1: `#+INCLUDE: "code/basic.sv" :src systemverilog :range-begin "// Example 1" :range-end "// End of Example 1"`. Snippet 2: `#+INCLUDE: "code/basic.sv" :src systemverilog :range-begin "// Example 2" :range-end "// End of Example 2"`. The execution is flawless! Thanks for implementing this **this** quick!

Answer (score 5):

The best way I can think of is to update these numbers immediately
before exporting or before evaluating.

### The Updater

This is the function that goes through the buffer. You can bind it to
a key, or add it to a hook. The following code updates the lines
*whenever you save the file*, but if your use case is different, just
find out which hook you need! (org-mode is *full* of hooks)

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'endless/update-includes)

(defun endless/update-includes (&rest ignore)
  "Update the line numbers of all #+INCLUDE:s in current buffer.
Only looks at INCLUDEs that already have a line number listed!
This function does nothing if not in org-mode, so you can safely
add it to `before-save-hook'."
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward-regexp
              "^\\s-*#\\+INCLUDE: *\"\\([^\"]+\\)\".*:lines *\"\\([-0-9]+\\)\""
              nil 'noerror)
        (let* ((file (expand-file-name (match-string-no-properties 1)))
               (lines (endless/decide-line-range file)))
          (when lines
            (replace-match lines :fixedcase :literal nil 2)))))))
```

### The Regexps

This is where you define the regexps which will be used as the first
and last lines to be included. You can give a list of regexps for
each file extension.

```
(defcustom endless/extension-regexp-map 
  '(("sv" ("^class\\b" . "^endclass\\b") ("^enum\\b" . "^endenum\\b")))
  "Alist of regexps to use for each file extension.
Each item should be
    (EXTENSION (REGEXP-BEGIN . REGEXP-END) (REGEXP-BEGIN . REGEXP-END))
See `endless/decide-line-range' for more information."
  :type '(repeat (cons string (repeat (cons regexp regexp)))))
```

### The background worker

This is the guy that does most of the work.

```
(defun endless/decide-line-range (file)
  "Visit FILE and decide which lines to include.
The FILE's extension is used to get a list of cons cells from
`endless/extension-regexp-map'. Each cons cell is a pair of
regexps, which determine the beginning and end of region to be
included. The first one which matches is used."
  (let ((regexps (cdr-safe (assoc (file-name-extension file)
                                  endless/extension-regexp-map)))
        it l r)
    (when regexps
      (save-match-data
        (with-temp-buffer
          (insert-file file)
          (while regexps
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (setq it (pop regexps))
            (when (search-forward-regexp (car it) nil 'noerror)
              (setq l (line-number-at-pos (match-beginning 0)))
              (when (search-forward-regexp (cdr it) nil 'noerror)
                (setq regexps nil
                      r (line-number-at-pos (match-end 0))))))
          (when r (format "%s-%s" l (+ r 1))))))))
```

Comment: If I may suggest, edebug the two functions and then invoke the first one with M-x. That should be very informative. :-)

Comment: The function by itself runs fine. But the hook needs to pass an argument to the function it is calling. From the docs for `org-export-before-processing-hook`, `Every function in this hook will be called with one argument: the
back-end currently used, as a symbol`. As we are not passing any argument, we get the error `run-hook-with-args: Wrong number of arguments`. Now I am not sure what argument to add to `endless/update-includes`... `(&optional dummy)` ?

Comment: @kaushalmodi oops, my bad. I've updated the answer. You can use thing you wrote as well.

Comment: OK.. adding `(&optional dummy)` actually worked! But an interesting side-effect of calling the function via hook. If I call the function using `M-x`, it modifies the `.org` file with the updated line numbers. But if I simply export to html and allow the hook to call the function, the updated line numbers are reflected only in the exported file, NOT in the `.org` file.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Yes, that's how org hooks work. You can add it to before-save-hook instead.

Comment: Thanks! I have also added this function call to `before-save-hook`. Works great! I have also modified your solution with a suggested change for #+INCLUDE regex and a fix to set the "r" line number correctly.

Comment: @kaushalmodi great! What was wrong with the r line number?

Comment: From http://orgmode.org/manual/Include-files.html, "You can also include a portion of a file by specifying a lines range using the :lines parameter. The line at the upper end of the range will not be included." Example: `#+INCLUDE: "~/.emacs" :lines "5-10"` <-- This includes lines 5 to 10, 10 excluded. In your function, `r` is the line containing `endclass` (for example). So if we set `:lines "l-r"`, the `rth` line won't be exported. So the exported formats won't show the line with `endclass`. So you need to increment `r` by 1.

Comment: @kaushalmodi I see, that's good to know!